# validating textbox one and textbox two or leave it empty

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how can i validate textbox1 and textbox 2.

- here is the thing i needed.

  - if i fill in textbox1 then i must fill in textbox2 if either one is empty must show error message.
  - if both both textboxes are empty then no error, proceed to the result
  - how to do that, can anyone show me how to do

-the bellow code is where i just validate the date either greater than or not

```
Private Sub cvCmpDate_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles cvCmpDate.ServerValidate
    If CompareMyDate.CompareDate(txtDateStart.Text.Trim, txtDateEnd.Text.Trim) Then
        cvCmpDate.ErrorMessage = "* Activation Start Date cannot greater than Activation End Date."
        args.IsValid = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Case True
    Case String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtDateStart.Text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtDateEnd.Text)
        ' Show Error
    Case String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtDateEnd.Text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtDateStart.Text)
        ' Show Error
    Case CompareMyDate.CompareDate(txtDateStart.Text.Trim, txtDateEnd.Text.Trim)
        cvCmpDate.ErrorMessage = "* Activation Start Date cannot greater than Activation End Date."
        args.IsValid = False
End Select
```